# rewrite rule in htaccess with . (dot)

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

hi this is my first time in stackoverflow so nice to meet you all :)
i have my .htaccess file

```
RewriteRule ^folder/([^/.]+)(/?)$ page.php?x=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^folder/([^/.]+)/([^/.]+)(/?)$ page.php?x=$1&y=$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^folder/([^/.]+)/([^/.]+)/([^/.]+)(/?)$ page.php?x=$1&y=$2&z=$3 [L]
```

it work with

```
http://localhost/test/folder/hello/001/
```

and

```
http://localhost/test/folder/hello/001/1/
```

but with . (dot) doesn't work

```
http://localhost/test/folder/hello/001.1/
```

how can i do it and thinks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
RewriteRule ^folder/([^/.]+)(/?)$ page.php?x=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^folder/([^/.]+)/([^/]+)(/?)$ page.php?x=$1&y=$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^folder/([^/.]+)/([^/.]+)/([^/.]+)(/?)$ page.php?x=$1&y=$2&z=$3 [L]
```

Answer (score 3):

Remove dot from your negative character class:

```
# skip rewriting for valid files/directories
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

RewriteRule ^folder/([^/]+)/?$ page.php?x=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^folder/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ page.php?x=$1&y=$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^folder/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ page.php?x=$1&y=$2&z=$3 [L]
```

PS: You need first rule here to skip rewriting for valid files/directories